# Neat way to loop with both index and value in Matlab

Tags: matlab

A lot of my loops look like this:

```
items = [3,14,15,92];
for item_i = 1:numel(items)
    item = items(item_i);
    % ...
end
```

This looks a bit messy to me. Is there some loop construct that lets me loop through the items and carry the index at the same time?

I'm looking for a syntax along the lines of `for item_i as item = items` or `for [item_i item] = items`.

Comment: Regardless of that it 'feels wrong' to do double work. I still think that this solution is most easy/natural to read.

Comment: I find the accepted answer both shorter and more readable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Similar to Chris Taylor's answer you could do this:

```
function [ output ] = Enumerate( items )
output = struct('Index',num2cell(1:length(items)),'Value',num2cell(items));
end


items = [3,14,15,92];
for item = Enumerate(items)
   item.Index
   item.Value
end
```

The Enumerate function would need some more work to be general purpose but it's a start and does work for your example.

This would be okay for small vectors but you wouldn't want to do this with any sizable vectors as performance would be an issue.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that there is no way of doing this. A trick I've used in the past is to exploit the fact that Matlab loops over the *columns* of a matrix, so you can define a function `enumerate` that adds an index row to the top of a matrix:

```
function output = enumerate(x)
   output = [1:size(x,2); x];
end
```

and then use it like this:

```
for tmp = enumerate(items)
    index = tmp(1);
    item  = tmp(2:end);
end
```

but that's not really any better than what you were doing originally. It would be nice if à la Python you could so something like

```
for [index,item] = enumerate(items)
    # loop body
end
```

where `enumerate` is a function that returns two matrices of the same length, but... you can't.

Comment: +1: This is what I'm also using now and then, except that my syntax is `for k = [items; 1:length(items)]` if `items` is a matrix, or `for k = [items; num2cell(1:length(items))]` for the cell array counterpart.

Answer (score 2):

I will occasionally do something like this

```
arr = {'something', 'something else'};
arrayfun(@(x, y)sprintf('%s (item %i)', x{:}, y), arr, 1:length(arr), ...
    'UniformOutput', false)
```

But this is only useful in very specific situations (specifically, those same situations where you would use `arrayfun` to shorten syntax), and to be honest the way you were doing it initially is probably better for most cases - anything else will probably obfuscate your intent.

Comment: In your example you can avoid `arrayfun` altogether by doing `arr = [arr; num2cell(1:length(arr))]; sprintf('%s (item %d)\n', arr{:})` :)

Comment: @EitanT: Nice! Didn't know about `num2cell`. Although that code returns a `char` array and not a `cell`.

Comment: You are right. Then use `textscan(sprintf('%s (item %d)\n', arr{:}), '%s', 'delimiter', '')` to split the result into cells :)

Answer (score 1):

Will this work for you?

```
k = 0;
for ii = items
  k = k + 1;  %% The index
  item = ii;  
  % ...
end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I need to reference the item index within the loop, e.g. in order to store calculations on the right position in a matrix.

Comment: I edited the answer now. Should work, but I would probably rather use your original solution.