# Decimal increments in for loop matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop

How to do decimal increments in for loop with arrays. This is the code i have written.

```
for i=1:0.1:10,
a(i)=i
end
```

Advance thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for indexing you need to introduce another variable, like

```
jj = 1;
for ii=1:0.1:10
       a(jj)=ii
       jj = jj+1;
end
```

or

```
for ii=1:1:10/0.1
       a(ii)=ii*0.1;
end
```

also have a look at the `sub2ind` function if you just want to store the counter in a vector.

another alternative. I don't know what your loop is doing, but at what I'm guessing I would do it as follows:

```
A = 1:0.1:10;
for ii=1:1:length(A)
       do something;
end
```

Comment: i want to save decimal ii value in arrays eg JJ[1]=1,jj[2]=1.1,JJ[3]=1.2 ...etc

Answer (score 3):

You can do this without a counter variable if you use the helper function Enumerate.

```
for i=Enumerate(1:0.1:10)
   a(i.Index)=i.Value;
end

function [ output ] = Enumerate( items )
   output = struct('Index',num2cell(1:length(items)),'Value',num2cell(items));
end
```

This is a similar question to [Neat way to loop with both index and value in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395866/neat-way-to-loop-with-both-index-and-value-in-matlab/16396473#16396473)

Answer (score 2):

*"i want to save decimal ii value in arrays eg JJ[1]=1,jj[2]=1.1,JJ[3]=1.2 ...etc"*

What's wrong with this ?

`JJ=1:0.1:10;`

Comment: I asked myself the same thing, but I guessed it wouldn't be the general purpose of the loop ;)